# ImportError: cannot import name 'DIFFUSERS_SLOW_IMPORT' from 'diffusers.utils'

Tags: python

When using diffusers like

```
from diffusers import AutoencoderKL, DDPMScheduler, UNet2DConditionModel
```

I get the following error:

```
ImportError: cannot import name 'DIFFUSERS_SLOW_IMPORT' from 'diffusers.utils' (/opt/conda/lib/python3.10/site-packages/diffusers/utils/__init__.py)
```

Also tried downgrading the version to 0.26.3 , but didn't help.

Diffusers version : 0.27.2

Answer (score 0):

Solved it, problem was with conflicting dependencies, once i cleaned up the conda and pip env, it was fine.

```
!python -m pip uninstall diffusers -y && conda uninstall diffusers -y
!conda clean -ay
!python -m pip cache purge
```